# Traverse Nested JSON Objects - YUI AutoComplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, yui

Say I have two different unrelated JSON Objects returned from separate AJAX requests

```
content: [{...}]
    0: {...}
        userId: "22"
        name: "Kevin Johnson"
        Manager: {…}
            managerId: "123"
            name: "Ryan Burke" //will be set as "searchValue"

content: [{...}]
    0: {...}
        companyId: "345"
        companyName: "Trucks-R-Us" //will be set as "searchValue"
        Building: {…}
            buildingId: "5"
            section: "North-West"
```

The attributes I've marked will be stored in a variable called `searchValue` (note they are not on the same level)

Can I access `searchValue` using [YUI's AutoComplete](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/autocomplete/) plugin to locate the attributes I've specified using the combination of `resultListLocator` and `resultTextLocator`, regardless of what the `key` of the attribute is named or how nested the attribute is?

```
 var autoComplete = new Y.AutoComplete({
    inputNode: '#search-string',
    resultListLocator: 'content',
    resultTextLocator: function( return /** Find searchValue within nested Object**/),
    resultHighlighter: 'phraseMatch',
    maxResults: 10
});
```

**Short version**: Can my objects be traversed until a match to `searchValue` is found?

Can elaborate if this isn't enough detail

Comment: an ajax request can only contain json representation of one object/array. Question doesn't make sense suggesting there are 2

Comment: Missed that @Charlietfl, updated my question